# Can not authenticate with UserInfo service with google-api-php-client library

Tags: php, google-api

I'm testing the OAuth2 service with google-api-php-client library to access UserInfo of logged users with their Google account. The code is taken from examples/userinfo/index.php with little change to cope with my host. When running the example, it passed through Google login form. When it came back to my site, an exception thrown as following.

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'apiIOException' with message 'HTTP Error: (0) couldn't connect to host' in /home/ztbmwjhd/public_html/apis/at/googleplus/google-api-php-client/src/io/apiCurlIO.php:120
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ztbmwjhd/public_html/apis/at/googleplus/google-api-php-client/src/io/apiCurlIO.php(46): apiCurlIO-&gt;makeRequest(Object(apiHttpRequest))
#1 /home/ztbmwjhd/public_html/apis/at/googleplus/google-api-php-client/src/io/apiREST.php(55): apiCurlIO-&gt;authenticatedRequest(Object(apiHttpRequest))
#2 /home/ztbmwjhd/public_html/apis/at/googleplus/google-api-php-client/src/service/apiServiceResource.php(151): apiREST::execute(Object(apiServiceRequest))
#3 /home/ztbmwjhd/public_html/apis/at/googleplus/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/apiPlusService.php(207): apiServiceResource-&gt;__call('get', Array)
#4 /home/ztbmwjhd/public_html/apis/at/googleplus/google-plus-access.php(40): PeopleServiceResource-&gt;get('me')
#5 /home/ztbmwjhd/public_html/apis/at/googleplus/index.php(2): include_once('/home/ztbmwjhd/...')
#6 {main}
  throw in /home/ztbmwjhd/public_html/apis/at/googleplus/google-api-php-client/src/io/apiCurlIO.php on line 120
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The error "HTTP Error: (0) couldn't connect to host" typically means theres a problem between your server and google. Are you connecting through a proxy?

Also, try to run "curl https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis" from your command line.

Comment: Thanks Chirag, I don't use proxy. It seems that "curl  https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=<token>" is not working

Comment: What type of error are you getting? Can you try "curl -v URL" for more verbose logging?